# What is wrong with this Sudoku Game?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, sudoku

Before you, you have a game. There's something wrong with this game. Can you figure out what it is?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

No, really, there's something wrong with this. Why isn't this a valid sudoku?

Comment: What is the purpose of this puzzle? To make a list of all the rules this sudoku violates? To create a correct sudoku from this one?

Comment: @Sumurai8 to make a list of all the rules this sudoku violates is correct. I'm sorry, i'll add that, I thought that was clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all is not filled in correctly.
Let's take the top left 3x3 square. It has 2 times 2 and 4 and 3 times 3.
Same goes for other 3x3 squares.
Actually all 3x3 squares are wrong because they contain 2 digits 1 time, 2 digits 2 times and 1 digit 3 times. The rest of 4 digits are missing.

Side note: the matrix is build like this:

first row all digits 1 to 9 ordered ascending.
Row n+1 is row n but the left most number is moved to the right side.

Comment: It wasn't as obvious to me as it was to you :)

Answer (score 2):

To correct this

> I think there are just a little shift's required and it should be good enough. Keep the first line 3 number group(1, 2, 3) intact and move the next pair of three numbers (4, 5, 6) & (7, 8, 9) below it until you reach level 4. Now, your second line 3 numbers(in the original square)(2, 3, 4) will be positioned at line 4, move the next part of three numbers below it. Go ahead and perform same actions filling column's 1, 2 and 3 until you solve it.

Finally you will get this

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
>  [7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
>  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>  [8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
>  [6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>  [9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

For rules -

> Visit [Sudoku Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku)

Hope I didn't messed it up. Didn't check thoroughly.